# Slicing items in a (key: value, value) dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to slice items in a (key: value, value) dictionary. As you can see I've written a for statement in the show_menu function that begins printing out the menu. But I want it to continue printing the menu from where it left off after the ("\nSides") print statement.

At the moment, the correct descriptions are being printed, in the second for statement in the show_menu function, but not the right idx, food, or price - (restarting count/items from the top).

```
MENU = {1 : ("Ham & Cheese", 5),
        2 : ("Cheesy Garlic", 5),
        3 : ("Hawaiian", 5),
        4 : ("Classic Cheese", 5),
        5 : ("Classic Veggie", 5),
        6 : ("Margherita", 8.50),
        7 : ("Hot & Spicy Veggie", 8.50),
        8 : ("Pepperoni", 8.50),
        9 : ("Meat Lovers", 8.50),
        10: ("Buffalo Chicken", 8.50),
        11 : ("Chicken Supreme", 8.50),
        12 : ("Beyond Beef", 8.50),
        13 : ("Crinkle-Cut Fries", 5.50),
        14 : ("Garlic Bread", 4.49),
        15 : ("Chicken Tenders", 8.99),
        16 : ("Coca Cola (1.5L)", 4.79),
        17 : ("Sprite (1.5L)", 4.79),
        18 : ("Pump (750ml)", 3.50)
        }


FOOD_DESC = ["Marinara tomato sauce topped with a layer of tender ham and lashings of mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Served with garlicky aioli, marinara tomato sauce, and lots of creamy mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Loaded with mozzarella cheese, ham, and chunks of delicious pineapple on top. A true Kiwi classic.", 
             "Stretchy, gooey, melting mozzarella, generously layered over traditional marinara tomato sauce.",
             "Juicy pineapple, green pepper, and red onion topped with mozzarella for a vibrant flavour explosion.", 
             "Freshly chopped tomatoes, a drizzle of pesto, and mounds of bubbling mozzarella.", 
             "Our explosive combination of jalapenos, red onion, green and red capsicum, and melted mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Meltingly delicious mozzarella, traditional marinara tomato sauce, with a pepperoni kick. An authentic pizza.", 
             "A variety of meats piled on top of classic marinara sauce and topped with BBQ sauce, satisfy all your meaty cravings.", 
             "Iconic Buffalo sauce, a hot shot of jalapenos, pieces of Southern-style fried chicken, and a creamy ranch drizzle.", 
             "Over juicy chicken breast, red onion, and the cheesy richness of mozzarella, our tangy BBQ sauce tastes wonderful.", 
             "Covered with loads of melted mozzarella cheese, red onion, and well-seasoned meat.", 
             "Perfectly seasoned, crisp-cut, and lightly browned.", "Fresh from the oven, buttery and garlicky, with a parsley garnish.", 
             "Flavorful chicken wings. Marinated in spices and fried till golden."]

def show_menu():
    print("*"*100 + "\n" + "Menu:\n".center(65))
    #Separately displays the items in the Pizza category.
    print("Pizzas")
    for (idx, (food, price)), desc in zip(MENU.items(), FOOD_DESC[0]) :
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n      {desc}\n")
    print("\nSides")
    for (idx, (food, price)), desc in zip(MENU.items(), FOOD_DESC[1]) :
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n      {desc}\n")    

show_menu()
```

Comment: You have 18 items in the MENU dictionary, but only 15 items in the FOOD_DESC list. Are there any missing descriptions?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the MENU dictionary and FOOD_ITEMS list are unbalanced, why would you separate these things? Surely it makes more sense for the descriptions to be in the MENU dictionary. Also, if FOOD_DESC[0] is passed to *zip()* it will just return the individual characters in the string

Comment: "nested dictionary"... I only see a `dict[int, tuple]` and no nested dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

You had a few problems, the first one is that the items in the two lists didn't match, I fixed that by removing the last 3 items and putting them in another list. That makes a lot of sense to me because apparently, they need a different behavior since they do not have a description.
The second problem is that you added a `[0]` and a `[1]` after FOOD_DESC in the 2 for loops, this is not correct.

```
for (idx, (food, price)), desc in zip(MENU.items(), FOOD_DESC[0]) :
    print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n      {desc}\n")
for (idx, (food, price)), desc in zip(MENU.items(), FOOD_DESC[1]) :
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n      {desc}\n")
```

So I removed them. After that, the only problem that remains is that the second loop doesn't need the FOOD_DESC list so we simply remove that part:

```
for idx, (side, price) in SIDES.items():
    print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n")
```

Final refactored result:

```
MENU = {1 : ("Ham & Cheese", 5),
        2 : ("Cheesy Garlic", 5),
        3 : ("Hawaiian", 5),
        4 : ("Classic Cheese", 5),
        5 : ("Classic Veggie", 5),
        6 : ("Margherita", 8.50),
        7 : ("Hot & Spicy Veggie", 8.50),
        8 : ("Pepperoni", 8.50),
        9 : ("Meat Lovers", 8.50),
        10: ("Buffalo Chicken", 8.50),
        11 : ("Chicken Supreme", 8.50),
        12 : ("Beyond Beef", 8.50),
        13 : ("Crinkle-Cut Fries", 5.50),
        14 : ("Garlic Bread", 4.49),
        15 : ("Chicken Tenders", 8.99),
        }
SIDES = {
        16 : ("Coca Cola (1.5L)", 4.79),
        17 : ("Sprite (1.5L)", 4.79),
        18 : ("Pump (750ml)", 3.50)

}

FOOD_DESC = ["Marinara tomato sauce topped with a layer of tender ham and lashings of mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Served with garlicky aioli, marinara tomato sauce, and lots of creamy mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Loaded with mozzarella cheese, ham, and chunks of delicious pineapple on top. A true Kiwi classic.", 
             "Stretchy, gooey, melting mozzarella, generously layered over traditional marinara tomato sauce.",
             "Juicy pineapple, green pepper, and red onion topped with mozzarella for a vibrant flavour explosion.", 
             "Freshly chopped tomatoes, a drizzle of pesto, and mounds of bubbling mozzarella.", 
             "Our explosive combination of jalapenos, red onion, green and red capsicum, and melted mozzarella cheese.", 
             "Meltingly delicious mozzarella, traditional marinara tomato sauce, with a pepperoni kick. An authentic pizza.", 
             "A variety of meats piled on top of classic marinara sauce and topped with BBQ sauce, satisfy all your meaty cravings.", 
             "Iconic Buffalo sauce, a hot shot of jalapenos, pieces of Southern-style fried chicken, and a creamy ranch drizzle.", 
             "Over juicy chicken breast, red onion, and the cheesy richness of mozzarella, our tangy BBQ sauce tastes wonderful.", 
             "Covered with loads of melted mozzarella cheese, red onion, and well-seasoned meat.", 
             "Perfectly seasoned, crisp-cut, and lightly browned.", "Fresh from the oven, buttery and garlicky, with a parsley garnish.", 
             "Flavorful chicken wings. Marinated in spices and fried till golden."]

def show_menu():
    print("*"*100 + "\n" + "Menu:\n".center(65))
    #Separately displays the items in the Pizza category.
    print("Pizzas")
    for (idx, (food, price)), desc in zip(MENU.items(), FOOD_DESC) :
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n      {desc}\n")
    print("\nSides")
    for idx, (side, price) in SIDES.items():
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {food : <45} ${price:.2f}\n")

show_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the dictionary of food items has 18 properties while the food descriptions list has 15 items. This means that after a certain index, your list will be out of range and you will get an error if you do not predict this case.

Second, you don't need 2 loops if the only thing linking the two structures is their position in their respective structures (list and dict).

Third, why are you using a dictionary for the food items and a list for the descriptions? Why are they not both in one list or dict? Are there more descriptions corresponding to the same item? If so, how do you make the connection between the two?

Anyway, here is something that will work:

```
def show_menu():
    print(("*"*100 + "\n" + "Menu:\n".center(65)))
    for (idx, item) in enumerate(MENU):
        item = MENU[item]
        print(f"[{idx : <2}]: {item[0] : <45} ${item[1]:.2f}\n")
        if len(FOOD_DESC) > idx-1:
            print(f"{FOOD_DESC[idx-1]}\n")
        else:
            print("There is no description available for this food item.")
```

To be clear, this will work as expected by OP but is not a real solution to the problem. A real solution would be to restructure the descriptions and the food items in a way that the description is inside of the food item, or at least have an explicit descriptor as to which description is assigned to which food item.

```
food_items = [...{"price" : 10, "name": "Omelette Du Fromage", "description" : "French dish used to pick up chicks in children's cartoons. "}....]
```

This is much simpler to read and loop through.

Comment: In this way, you do not print Pizzas just after the menu and Sides after 15 iterations, add an if to get there :)

Comment: My answer is as clear and precise as the question was. In any case, that is a minor edit that OP can do themself.